# WordPress Migration to subdomain corrupted by incorrect path

Tags: mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, config

I am working on a project that involves migrating a WordPress installation from point A to point B.  It should be fairly simple, but neither manual nor plugin-based transfers are working.  To explain:

Point A is a fairly standard installation of 'demo.com', and I am trying to migrate it to a subdomain (point B), say 'c.example.com'.  Of course I can migrate the code, plugins, themes, etc just fine, however when I bring over the database, everything goes haywire (and I have made updates to the site URL / home URL / some permalink structure within the database).

A snippet of code from within the `<head>` tag shows some interesting information:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="parent-style-css" href="http://c.#wp-content/themes/Example_theme/style.css?ver=4.4.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="style-css-css" href="http://c.#wp-content/themes/Example_theme/style.css?ver=4.4.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="layout-css" href="http://c.#wp-content/themes/Example_theme/css/layout.css?ver=4.4.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="main-css" href="http://c.#wp-content/themes/Example_theme/css/main.css?ver=4.4.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="shortcodes-css" href="http://c.#wp-content/themes/Example_theme/css/shortcodes.css?ver=4.4.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="mediaelement-css" href="http://c.#wp-includes/js/mediaelement/mediaelementplayer.min.css?ver=2.18.1" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="prettyPhoto-css" href="http://c.#wp-content/themes/Example_theme/css/prettyPhoto.css?ver=4.4.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="responsive-css" href="http://c.#wp-content/themes/Example_theme/css/responsive.css?ver=4.4.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="instag-slider-css" href="http://c.#wp-content/plugins/instagram-slider-widget/assets/css/instag-slider.css?ver=1.2.1" type="text/css"
```

Taking a closer look, you can see that the href/path does not include the 'example.com' domain name, and instead is replaced with a "#".

```
http://c.#wp-content/themes/Example_theme/css/responsive.css?ver=4.4.2
```

Further notes, I have updated the wp-config file to define the WP_HOME and WP_SITE URLs, and this has no effect.  .htaccess is also corrected for the subdomain (which additionally has no effect), it reads:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /c/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . //index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The cause of this seems to be *somewhere* within the database, however there may be a file somewhere that is controlling this.

Any assistance is welcome, and very appreciated.

Thank you again for your time with my issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try it from scratch. Clean all of the subdomain files & database. Then, copy all of the example.com files to the subdomain. After that, export all SQL database (relevant to the wp installation) & import it into subdomain's db.

After that edit wp-config.php & put relevant info in those lines:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'your_db_name');
/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'your_subdomains_db_user');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'your_subdomains_db_pass');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

...

$table_prefix  = 'your_subdomain_db_table_prefix';
```

After that manipulation use this script https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

All you need to do is copy it into your subdomain, access it's main file & use it to replace all db entries of "example.com" to "c.example.com".

That's all, after that you should have fully functional WP copy of your example.com at your subdomain.

Also, you can read the codex for more info https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress